# How to access run list during chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra

How do I refer to the active run list at converge time?

I'm trying to write out the run list into a json attribute file for an AMI that I'm building with chef-client connected to a chef server. My chef-client version is 12.14.89.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean, probably `node.run_list`, which is an instance of `Chef::RunList`. `node.run_list.to_json` will give you the run list formatted in JSON.

Comment: I'm still debugging my template (it's probably broken for other reasons), so I haven't yet confirmed that this solves my issue. Would it be a problem if I amended the question to include how to determine if a particular recipe belongs to the current run_list?

Comment: For that you want `node['recipes'].include?('whatever')`. That will also grok `include_recipe` stuffs.

Comment: node.run_list.to_json outputs only the JSON Array. In order to use it like I need it, the line should look like this: `"run_list": <%= node.run_list.to_json %>`.

Comment: Also, @coderanger, what belongs in the 'whatever' portion? Should the recipe be rendered as `cookbook::recipe` or `recipe[cookbook::recipe]` or some other option? I tried `cookbook::recipe`, and it didn't seem to work, but I could have screwed it up some other way.

Comment: `cookbook::recipe` :) You can also look at the node attribute data via `knife node show` from your workstation to see what's in that array.